# Plot standard deviation from external datasource using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, std

I am trying to visualize a lineplot via seaborn, in which I want to plot the average and standard deviation of a column. As I am using large files (with millions of rows) the plot takes a while to load.

To reduce computational time, I pre-computed the average of the columns and the corresponding standard deviation. Subsequently, I use this pre-computed data as input for the lineplot, instead the supplying the complete Pandas dataframe.

This is the code I currently use:

```
df = open_pickle("data/experiment")
sns.lineplot(x="rho", y="wait_time_mean", hue="c", style="service_type", data=df)
```

This will only show the average. I was wondering if it would be possible to manually supply values for the standard deviation to seaborn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sns.lineplot` returns the Axes object of the plot which then can be used to draw on it. Assuming your standard deviation is also in `df` you can adapt your code in the following way, which now uses the matplotlib-function `fill_beetween`:

```
df = open_pickle("data/experiment")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="rho", y="wait_time_mean", hue="c", style="service_type", data=df)
ax.fill_between(df["rho"], y1=df["wait_time_mean"] - df["wait_time_std"], y2=df["wait_time_mean"] + df["wait_time_std"], alpha=.5)
```